# MySQL storage overhead issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie to MySQL. I have created a table with 277 columns and on addition of new columns i.e. 57 no of new columns it throws this error "Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs ". I tried converting all 277 the columns to BLOB and import these new columns but same issue continues. No idea where and how to resolve this. When I import these same new columns to cloud server it never imports and throws this error.

```
Here is the table.
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Aug 27, 2021 at 11:13 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.32-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.36

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `testing`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `reg`
--

CREATE TABLE `reg` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `grirno` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `grirdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `inwardagainst` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `suppliername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `supplierid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sup_billno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sup_billdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `returnasit` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `partname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `partnameid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `drawingno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `internal_rev` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pono` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `poqty` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `popendingqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `podeliverydate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `billedqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `receivedqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tcir` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `holdreason` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `str_status` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `str_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `str_remark_approval` blob NOT NULL,
  `str_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `str_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `str_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qad_status` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `qad_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `qad_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qad_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qad_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qad_purchase_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qad_purchase_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qad_purchase_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qad_purchase_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qad_purchase_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `irattachment` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `okqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `okcompletion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `okrejreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `rejqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rejcompletion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rejrejreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `frqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `frcompletion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `frrejreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `rwqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rwcompletion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rwrejreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `finalokqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `finalrejqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `finalfrqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `finalrwqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_status` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `account_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `account_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_status` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `purchase_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `purrejreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `purfrreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `purrwreason` blob NOT NULL,
  `debitamount` blob NOT NULL,
  `debitamount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `particular1` blob NOT NULL,
  `unitprice1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billedqty_unit1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `output1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `particular2` blob NOT NULL,
  `unitprice2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billedqty_unit2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `output2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `particular3` blob NOT NULL,
  `unitprice3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billedqty_unit3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `output3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `particular4` blob NOT NULL,
  `unitprice4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billedqty_unit4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `output4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalcgst` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalsgst` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totaligst` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalgrand` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bill_amt` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bill_reason` blob NOT NULL,
  `bill_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `reason1` blob NOT NULL,
  `remark1` blob NOT NULL,
  `amount1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reason2` blob NOT NULL,
  `remark2` blob NOT NULL,
  `amount2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reason3` blob NOT NULL,
  `remark3` blob NOT NULL,
  `amount3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reason4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `remark4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `amount4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reason5` blob NOT NULL,
  `remark5` blob NOT NULL,
  `amount5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taxtype9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cgstamount9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sgstamount9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `igstamount9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalamount_debit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalcgst_debit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalsgst_debit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totaligst_debit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `totalgrand_debit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billattach` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `rcrate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_debit` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_reason` blob NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_remark` blob NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_purchase_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_bill_issue` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dcissueno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dcissueid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dcgrirno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reg_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `reg_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `reg_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `edit_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `edit_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `edit_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `debitnoteno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `debitdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `costdevno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qualitydevno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reset_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billpassingno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cessamt1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cessamt2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cessamt3` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cessamt4` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cessamt5` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cesstype1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cesstype2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cesstype3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cesstype4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cesstype5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cesscgstper1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesscgstper2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesscgstper3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesscgstper4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesscgstper5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesssgstper1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesssgstper2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesssgstper3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesssgstper4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cesssgstper5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cessigstper1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cessigstper2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cessigstper3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cessigstper4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cessigstper5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `roundoff` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `totalquantity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `debit_terms` blob NOT NULL,
  `debit_notes` blob NOT NULL,
  `attachfile` blob NOT NULL,
  `totalcess` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtfinalokqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtfinalrejqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtfinalfrqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtfinalrwqty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rawid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rawmaterial` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rawunit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rawqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtcorrection_okqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtcorrection_rejqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtcorrection_frqty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtcorrection_total` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmt_total` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtqtyadded_remark` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtqtyadded_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtqtyadded_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mgmtqtyadded_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `delete_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `delete_date` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `delete_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `delete_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `against` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcno1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcdate1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcno1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcdate1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rwqtyrec1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dcremark1` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcno2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcdate2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcno2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcdate2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rwqtyrec2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dcremark2` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcno3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcdate3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcno3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcdate3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rwqtyrec3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dcremark3` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcno4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcdate4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcno4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplierdcdate4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rwqtyrec4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dcremark4` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `inwardbyid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `inwardbyname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `inwarddate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcid1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcid2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcid3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `againstdcid4` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `reg`
--
ALTER TABLE `reg`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `reg`
--
ALTER TABLE `reg`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: That sounds like MariaDB... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/

Comment: If you've got that many columns it suggests that your schema design needs a rethink. Those columns should probably be rows in a table.

Comment: The root cause is most probably the table design which is symptomatic of an un-normalised data structure.  Converting to BLOB is not a solution, just a possible workaround, and should at most be used `sparingly`. Definitely not on all columns.